# JavaFX - Inicializar componentes apenas quando a cena for solicitada

Tags: java, javafx

Estou tentando inicializar alguns componentes, porém percebi que o método initialize do controller do fxml é inicializado antes que a cena seja colocada no stage, esta é a maneira que eu uso para gerenciar as cenas:

**SceneManager.java**

```
package br.com.ivesti.ivarejo.util;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SceneManager {

    private static Stage mStage;

    private static Scene mSceneCadastrarUsuario, mSceneLogin, mSceneMainWindow;

    private static volatile SceneManager mInstance;

    private SceneManager(){
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize(){
        try {

            if (mSceneCadastrarUsuario == null)
                mSceneCadastrarUsuario = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ui/cadastrar_usuario_dialog.fxml")));


            if(mSceneLogin == null)
                mSceneLogin = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ui/login_dialog.fxml")));

            if(mSceneMainWindow == null) {
                mSceneMainWindow = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ui/dashboard_dialog.fxml")));
                mSceneMainWindow.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("../css/style.css").toString());
            }

        }catch (IOException | NullPointerException e){
            System.err.println("Falha em obter a cena: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    public void setStage(Stage stage){

        if(mStage == null){
            mStage = stage;
        }

    }

    public void changeScene(Scenes scenes){

        mStage.setResizable(false);

        switch (scenes){

            case CADASTRAR_USUARIO:
                mStage.setScene(mSceneCadastrarUsuario);
                break;

            case LOGIN:
                mStage.setScene(mSceneLogin);
                break;

            case MAIN_WINDOW:
                mStage.setResizable(true);
                mStage.setScene(mSceneMainWindow);
                break;

        }

    }

    public static SceneManager getManager(){

        if(mInstance == null){

            synchronized (SceneManager.class){

                if(mInstance == null)
                    mInstance = new SceneManager();

            }

        }

        return mInstance;
    }

    public enum Scenes{
        LOGIN, CADASTRAR_USUARIO, MAIN_WINDOW
    }

}
```

**DashboardController.java**

```
package br.com.ivesti.ivarejo.controllers;

import br.com.ivesti.ivarejo.util.Session;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class DashboardController implements Initializable {

    /*    Componentes    */

    @FXML
    private Text tUsuarioAtual;

    /*    Eventos    */

    @FXML
    private void onUsuariosClicked(ActionEvent event){
        tUsuarioAtual.setText(Session.getSession().getString("u_name"));
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        tUsuarioAtual.setText(Session.getSession().getString("u_name"));

    }

}
```

Então como fazer para `initialize` ser chamado apenas quando `SceneManager.getManager().changeScene(SceneManager.Scenes.MAIN_WINDOW);` for chamado?

Answer (score 0):

Eu posso estar equivocado, mas não seria simplesmente criar as variáveis e só seta-las no momento de usar o `FXMLLoader`, primeiro removeria isto:

```
    try {

        if (mSceneCadastrarUsuario == null)
            mSceneCadastrarUsuario = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ui/cadastrar_usuario_dialog.fxml")));


        if(mSceneLogin == null)
            mSceneLogin = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ui/login_dialog.fxml")));

        if(mSceneMainWindow == null) {
            mSceneMainWindow = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ui/dashboard_dialog.fxml")));
            mSceneMainWindow.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("../css/style.css").toString());
        }

    }catch (IOException | NullPointerException e){
        System.err.println("Falha em obter a cena: " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

E chamaria dentro do proprio switch assim:

```
    switch (scenes){

        case CADASTRAR_USUARIO:
            if (mSceneCadastrarUsuario == null) {
                mSceneCadastrarUsuario = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ui/cadastrar_usuario_dialog.fxml")));
            }

            mStage.setScene(mSceneCadastrarUsuario);
            break;

        case LOGIN:
            if(mSceneLogin == null) {
                mSceneLogin = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ui/login_dialog.fxml")));
            }

            mStage.setScene(mSceneLogin);
            break;

        case MAIN_WINDOW:
            mStage.setResizable(true);

            if(mSceneMainWindow == null) {
                mSceneMainWindow = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ui/dashboard_dialog.fxml")));
                mSceneMainWindow.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("../css/style.css").toString());
            }

            mStage.setScene(mSceneMainWindow);
            break;

    }
```

Você poderia até criar um método auxiliar para carregar as classes e o fxml e dentro dele aplicar o try/catch, se bem que se der erro no carregamento disto é porque foi durante o desenvolvimento que algo faltou e deveria ser corrigido.